# Check Motherboard Sensor Data in real time with c#

Tags: c#, cpu, sensors, temperature, motherboard

I have been looking for a solution to check fan speeds and temperature data from the motherboard's sensors in real time.

WMI seems to give you only one reading that never updates and every one seems to be saying to use Open Hardware Monitor but the documentation is horrible and I can't get the .dll working properly in C#.

Don't suggest Open Hardware Monitor in less you are prepared to cover the implementation.
There must be a reliable way to do this.

I'll eventually be running this as a script in unity if that helps. I can only use solutions that will work in .Net 2.0 or lower.

Comment: I should have included, I'm specifically looking for cpu but I want all available sensors as well.

Comment: Maybe your question should be about getting the DLL working for the solution that best fits your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583871/cant-get-openhardwaremonitorlib-dll-to-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The health reporting in the "hardware <-> driver <-> monitor software" stack is not standardized, and C# is a pretty unusual language to write hardware health stuff in, so your options will be quite limited. Sorry, OHM is probably your best bet...

Comment: Well I'm not opposed to writing it in C++ then importing the .dll. I'd love to use OHM but like I said, I think the documentation is garbage and for someone like me who isn't that savvy in linking .dll's and using third party programs i need more direction.