# Can't get OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll to work

Tags: c#, dll, hardware-interface, openhardwaremonitor

I've found very few examples of how to get OHM working in c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;

namespace OpenHardwareMonitorReport
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Computer computer = new Computer();
            computer.Open();

            var temps = new List<decimal>();
            foreach (var hardware in computer.Hardware)
            {
                if (hardware.HardwareType != HardwareType.CPU)
                    continue;
                hardware.Update();
                foreach (var sensor in hardware.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType != SensorType.Temperature)
                    {
                        if (sensor.Value != null)
                            temps.Add((decimal)sensor.Value);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (decimal temp in temps)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(temp);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This should display some sensor data but when I run it gives me this error:

Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\DLLTutorial\HardwareMonitor\HardwareMonitor\bin\Debug\HardwareMonitor.vshost.exe'.
Additional Information: A call to PInvoke function 'PInvokeDelegateFactoryInternalAssembly!PInvokeDelegateFactoryInternalWrapperType13::ADL_Main_Control_Create' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

I've downloaded the .dll from the OHM svn, put it in my project, added the reference to it and it crashes on the line "computer.Open();" with that error I posted above.

Please help!

Comment: I just downloaded the latest example and ran the code you provided. It worked fine on my machine. What version of Windows/.Net are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit, .Net 4.0

Comment: That's what I'm running as well. Did you install SP1?

Comment: Did you only include the OpenHardwareManagerLib.dll in your project? I only put that one file in my project's source folder.

Comment: I'm on SP1, thank you for your trying at least :)

Comment: Yes, I just added a reference to OpenHardwareManagerLib.dll. Do you also do the stupid windows 7 "unblock" on the zip after downloading it?

Comment: Umm no? what's unblock? I just unzip and and copied it into my project

Comment: When you download the .zip, you should right-click and then click "Unblock" before unzipping and using the DLL

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not seeing an option for "Unblock" when I right click the .zip

Comment: Should I see that option with all zip files?

Comment: I do. Here's and example: http://www.petri.co.il/unblock-files-windows-vista.htm (even though it says Vista)

Comment: AH! Unblock is not present when you right click, you have to do into properties and its in the general tab. Thx for that tidbit. I'm still getting the same error. I removed the reference, deleted the old file, readded the new unzipped and unblocked file.

Comment: I turned off the pInvokeStackUnbalance warning and it worked. This obviously is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a problem with my set up. It doesn't fail on other systems...Don't you hate it when that happens.